# using postgresql, how can I join tables , select all from left table and sum and count from right table?

Tags: postgresql

I want to select two fields from expense_projects (left table) and count rows and sum amount from expense_items (right table) with a where clause relating to left table. There may be no entries, in right table that correspond, in which case I want to return null or 0.

I would like to achieve the following:

```
project   item_count  item_spend
pr 1      19          298.54
pr 2      0           0
pr 3      2           18.73
```

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE expense_projects(
project_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
project_company_id int,
project_name text,
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE expense_items(
item_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
expense_project_id int, 
expense_company_id int,
user_id int,
item text,
amount numeric(10,2),
mop text, 
card_digits text,
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
);
```

So far, I have

```
SELECT i.expense_project_id, p.project_id, p.project_name, SUM(amount) AS item_amount, count(item) AS item_count FROM expense_items i, expense_projects p GROUP BY i.expense_project_id, p.project_id, p.project_name
```

which repeats the data for the one table that has entries in right table twice, so I get duplication becasue there are two projects for the left table but only data, in the right table) for one project. Also I do not know how to add the where clause.

In plain English I want:

```
SELECT p.project_name, p.project_id FROM expense_projects p (left table)
WHERE p.project_company_id = 2 (for example)
LEFT JOIN expense_items i ON p.project_id = i.expense_project_id
COUNT(item) AS item_count
SUM(amount) AS item_amount
GROUP BY p.project_id, p.project_name
```

all help gratefully received guys, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do what you want.

```
 SELECT 
        p.project_name, 
        p.project_id,
        COUNT(i.expense_project_id) AS item_count,
        SUM(COALESCE(amount,0)) AS item_amount
 FROM expense_projects p 
 LEFT JOIN expense_items i ON p.project_id = i.expense_project_id      
 WHERE p.project_company_id = 2
 GROUP BY p.project_id, p.project_name
```

Comment: thanks, getting a 503 response, logs don't say what is wrong though

Comment: error is PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SUM"
2015-03-23T11:39:49.378590+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 3:     SUM(COALESCE(amount,0)) AS item_amount

Comment: added tbl structure. Sorry, I attempted to edit your answer mistakenly.

Comment: Sorry, try again - I'd made two edits to the query and I think you got the first one which had an error. I've just checked the query, the syntax is (now) valid. Also, please ignore remark about timestamp, that's just the current time...

Comment: rock star, works great THANK YOU! Next question is how to do this with Sequel ORM and not raw SQL but that is for another day. I really appreciate your help.